# Proof-check: Ring Isomorphism of $\Bbb Z[x]/\left< x^3-x\right>$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Claim:** $\Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x^3-x\right> \simeq \Bbb Z[x]/\left< x\right>  \times\  \Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x^2-1\right> $

**My attempt:**

Here $\left< x^2-1\right> $ and $\left< x\right> $ are two ideals, where $1$ belongs to $\big(\left< x^2-1\right> +\left< x\right> \big)$, since $1=x^2-(x^2-1)$, so my claim holds true by Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Now I am checking, whether it can be further reducible or not.

Again we can show $\Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x\right> \simeq \Bbb Z$ by taking the surjective ring homomorphism $\phi\colon \Bbb Z[x]\to \Bbb Z$, such that $\phi(f(x))=f(0)$. Here $\text{ker}(\phi)=\left< x\right>$, so by the first ring isomorphism theorem $\Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x\right> \simeq \Bbb Z$, and $\Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x\right>  \times\  \Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x^2-1\right> \simeq\Bbb Z \times\  \Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x^2-1\right> $.

Now, since $1$ does not belong to $\big(\left< x-1\right> +\left< x+1\right> \big)$, where factorization of $(x^2-1)=(x+1)\cdot(x-1)$, we can't use CRT further on this or we can't break this quotient ring further.

So my ANSWER (after reducing the claim also) to this ring isomorphism is  $\Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x^3-x\right> $  $\simeq$  $\Bbb Z \times\  \Bbb Z[x]\ /\left< x^2-1\right> $. Is my explanation correct? Is it the most reduced version in isomorphism(even after reducing the claim)?

Comment: Looks good to me. You can use \langle, \rangle, and \to to make things look nicer. You should probably also give a reason why $1 \not\in \langle x-1\rangle + \langle x+1\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, actually, 1∉⟨x−1⟩+⟨x+1⟩ because for this 1/2 or some fraction should be there in Z to make the combination of (x+1) and (x-1) equals to 1, that is impossible. If I need the exact proof then what should I do?

Comment: The question doesn't ask about any further decomposition so that work is superfluous. Ditto for your remark about $\Bbb Z[x]/x \cong \Bbb Z.\,$ You need only your first paragraph.

Comment: Why did you ask the question?  Did you have doubts about the easy proof that  $\,1 \in (x) + (x^2-1)?$ If not, what did you doubt? It may  help to state the version of CRT you are using.

Comment: It sounds like you probably understand why $1 \not\in \langle x-1\rangle + \langle x+1\rangle$ but that you have trouble expressing it clearly. I'd say: given $f(x) = p(x) (x-1) + q(x) (x+1)$ with $p(x), q(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $2 \mid f(1)$, so $f(x) \neq 1$.

Comment: I had a doubt that whether this isomorphism can be decomposed further or not, if not then is my proof enough for this sum?

Comment: Yes, you need only the first paragraph. Saying more makes it look like you don't understand what the claimed isomorphism means.

Comment: As a simple analogy, it's like a proof of $\,x^3+x = x(x^2+1)$ adding the superfluous remark that $\,x^2+1\,$ is irreducible in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$  so that is the prime factorization. But the question only asks to prove said polynomial equality, not that it is further a factorization into primes (irreducibles). OP is a *structural* analog of this *elemental* example.

Comment: You shouldn't change the claim since it causes inconsistency with the comments. Better, append an Update or somesuch.

Comment: My two cents: while it's always important to understand the literal question asked and to answer that question rather than any other, it's vastly more important to correctly understand what's going on writ large. So, I didn't think much of the minor inconsistency between your literal claim and your actual discussion about further reduction. I certainly agree with Bill's stylistic remarks, but I usually assign style only 10% credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define ring epimorphisms $\pi_1:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z$ and $\pi_2:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z\times\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}$ by
$$\pi_1:f(x)\mapsto f(0)\;\;\;\;\;\pi_2:f(x)\mapsto f(x)+\langle x^2-1\rangle$$ so that $\Psi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z\times\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}$ is also a ring homomorphism where $$\Psi:f(x)\mapsto(\pi_1(f(x)),\pi_2(f(x)))$$
$$f(x)\in\ker(\Psi)\iff f(0)=0\;\land\;x^2-1\;|\;f(x)\iff x,x+1,x-1\;|\;f(x)$$
$$\therefore\;f(x)\in\ker(\Psi)\iff x^3-x\;|\;f(x)\;\;\;\;\;\therefore\;\ker(\Psi)=\langle x^3-x\rangle$$
Moreover, $(c,f(x)+\langle x^2-1\rangle)=\Psi(f(x)+(x^2-1)(f(0)-c))$ and thus $\Psi$ is an epimorphism.$$\therefore\;\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{\langle x^3-x\rangle}\approx\Bbb Z\times\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}$$